# Oracle Jar causing warning in Maven packaging

Tags: oracle, maven-2, jdbc

I have added my Oracle JDBC driver to my Maven repository and everything is working fine however I am still receiving warnings whenever I package my project. E.g.

```
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'com.oracle:ojdbc14:pom:10.2.0' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

How can I stop those warnings from showing up?

Comment: Well, does your package build all right?

Comment: Yes it does build alright. It just has warnings. Pascal cleared it up for me. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven is trying to get the `.pom` file of your Oracle driver because it can't find it in your local repository. A simple `ojdbc14-10.2.0.pom` with the following content would suffice:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
  <version>10.2.0</version>
</project>
```

You could create it manually or get it generated by Maven when invoking [`install:install-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) (to install it in your local repository) or [`deploy:deploy-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) (to install it in a remote repository) using the [`generatePom`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html#generatePom) optional parameter:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/path/to/ojdbc14.jar \
                         -DgroupId=com.oracle \
                         -DartifactId=ojdbc14 \
                         -Dversion=10.2.0 \
                         -Dpackaging=jar \
                         -DgeneratePom=true
```

The [`deploy:deploy-file`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) goal admits the same [`generatePom`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html#generatePom) optional parameter.

PS: My recommendation would be to use the [Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.1.0) drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html).

Comment: Thank you very much Pascal. That helped immensely.

Answer (score 0):

mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:/oraclexe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/jdbc/lib/ojdbc14.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc14 -Dversion=10.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true